# How to POST value to PHP in the same page using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I don't know if I'm just dumb. I have been trying to figure this out for the past 1hour. Please help!!

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="box" ></div>
<div id="box2"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
  $('#box').html("Test");

    //$('#box').attr('name','Indy');
    //var a= $('#box').attr('name');
    $.post(window.location, {name: 'John'});


});

</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

How do I pass the value? I know this works if the php is in a different file. But this is not the case here.

Comment: Is 1.php the file you posted?

Answer (score 18):

You won't be seeing the request's results because `$.post()` and all the AJAX functions run in the background, which doesn't refresh the page.

As for posting to the current page, just use the window's location:

```
$.post(window.location, {name: 'John'}, function(data) {
  alert('POST was successful. Server says: ' + data);
});
```

Comment: Actually I need to pass the value 'John' to the PHP code. This doesn't seem to be helping in that.

Comment: How do you know it isn't working? This code posts `name=John`.

Comment: I mean the print_r($_POST) returns just an empty array. I can see the parameters passed in Firebug so it is Posting to the same page, but somebody please explain why I'm not able to get the value in $_POST array.

Comment: How are you able to check what `print_r` outputs? When you reload the page, you aren't posting anything. You might be confused about POST and GET variables.

Comment: Ok, I am confused. But how do I pass the value to the PHP? I need this because I'm generating a PDF using PHP and a value must be passed from jQuery in the same page to PHP.

Comment: That above code should do just that. It must be a problem with your other code. Could you post the relevant chunks?

Comment: I have edited the code and added the whole thing. Still I don't get whats wrong with this.

Comment: You will not be able to *see* the results because the state of the page you request will not be the state of the page to which you sent the POST request. I can assure you the code works. You could try writing the POST data to a file if you don't believe me ;)

Comment: Oh crap. So you could have told me this in the begining..lol
Is there no other way to pass a variable from javascript to PHP in the same file?

Answer (score 1):

The $.post is an asynchronous posting the the same php file. You aren't going to see anything in the body of your page because

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Is after the `</html>` tag.

If you are wanting to post something to the php file, and then process it and have the results show up in the page, simply create a form that actually POSTs to the php file. AJAX isn't always the right answer.

Comment: How about using jSon to pass the value? I cannot use forms for my specific case.

Comment: You can't use forms? What kind of application can't use forms?

Answer (score 1):

you can try inserting this into your javascript code:

```
 $('some_button').click(function(){
      window.location = "http://your_site/page.php?name=John&var2="+param2;
 });
```

what this code do is adding some parameter into url and you can access that in your php page using GET.
for example:

```
 if(isset($_GET['name'])){
      echo $_GET['name'];
 }
```

Comment: This is a GET request, OP wants to POST.